# Test class at 65%

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

my Test_Unit class passes @ 65% only, I'm not sure why is that?

**Error message is:**

> BranchController_Test  testBranchMethods   System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject 
>   Stack Trace: Class.TestData.CreateLead: line 122, column 1 Class.BranchController_Test.testBranchMethods: line 30, column 1

```
 @isTest
private class BranchController_Test {

    static testMethod void testBranchMethods() {

        set<string> sZips = new set<string>();
        set<id> sBranch = new set<id>();

        //bBEGIN: S-444338 When wee run this test class we are getting Mixed DML Operations error, to avoid this we need modify this TEST Apex class
        User thisUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
        system.runAs(thisUser){
        //Branch__c b = TestData.CreateBranch(1, '99999');

        Branch__c b = new Branch__c(name = 'Neil Test Branch');
        insert b;
        sBranch.add(b.Id);

        ZipCode__c z = TestData.CreateZips('10001', b.Id);
        insert z;
        sZips.add(z.Name);


        User u = TestData.CreateUser(1);
        insert u;

        IAASettings__c iaa = TestData.CreateSetting('DefaultOwnerId', u.Id);
        insert iaa;

        Account acct = TestData.CreateAccount(1, '10001');
        insert acct;

        Lead ld = TestData.CreateLead(1, '10001');
        insert ld;

        list<ZipCode__c> zipcodes = BranchController.LookupBranchByZip(sZips);
        list<Branch__c> branches = BranchController.LookupOwnerByBranch(sBranch); 

        string branchAdd = BranchController.BranchAddress(b);
        string acctAdd = BranchController.AccountAddress(acct);
        string leadAdd = BranchController.LeadAddress(ld);

        string nullString1 = BranchController.CheckForNull(acctAdd);
        string nullStrin2 = BranchController.CheckForNull('null');

        //BranchController.CalculateAccountDistance(b.Id, acct.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Also i'm trying to fix the error in the Apex class,this method is the main reason of the errors. any help would help. thanks.
[image]

Comment: Maybe help us by providing the exact error message? Also your test class is not testing anything. It is just running code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your Test_Unit Class never call your method CalculateDistance.

That can be for many reason, you can execute CalculateDistance in your test class, if it has sense.

Otherwise you can check if your data and actions in test class are able to trigger the execution of CalculateDistance.

I'd need more details for a comprehensive answer.

Comment: since the CalculateDistance is a @future method and i'm not calling it in the Unit_Test. if I use System.Start() and System.End() would fix it?
f.y.i. never used start() and end() would you provide an example? thanks

Comment: Yes, try add  Test.startTest();
  
   // code that trigger your method //
  Test.stopTest();    I didn't notice you don't do that

Comment: classes/BranchController_Test.cls: Variable does not exist: leadsFR (Line: 51, Column: 20)

Comment: I can't find leadsFR in your code, but Line: 51 of your test class cause this error. I don't know which is line 51 because your code changed. sorry for not more detail

Comment: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: User.get(User) (Line: 51,
Test.startTest(); 
        System.runAs(User.get(u))
            {
                insert ld;
                system.debug('testing' + ld);
            }       
        Test.stopTest();

Comment: I think it's here the problem: User.get(u) . what is User? A list of users? and 'u' is a key? before you did system.runAs(thisUser), that doesn't work anymore for you?

Comment: As you see below User is a single user defined in the same test class
User u = TestData.CreateUser(1);
        insert u;

Comment: So do System.runAs(u){ //code// }

Comment: please if you fixed the error and my comments were useful for you, vote my answer @templar

Comment: Thanks Viviana and this is how fixed it
 Test.StartTest();
            BranchController.CalculateDistance(b.id, acct.id, b.name);
        Test.StopTest();
        }